# How to prove this result about perpendicular bisector?

Tags: geometry

I have been working on this question for many hours.  Thanks for your help.

Given: $\overline{BD}$ is the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AC}$

Prove: $\angle BAC=\angle BCA$ (equal and congruent)

[image: image of the shape]

Comment: Hint: Show that $\triangle BAE$ and $\triangle BCE$ are congruent, using Side-Angle-Side.

Comment: so AE=EC and BC=BC. what is the angle then for Side-Angle-Side, <AEB = <CEB? and if that's right what congruence postulate can back it up?

Comment: Depends on the details of the axiomatization. One of Euclid's axioms is that all right angles are congruent.

Comment: You don't even need the axiom actually, because the fact that these 2 angles are congruence is just the definition of perpendicularity.

Comment: Though it seem as though its 90 degrees, we cant assume that it is, the problem did not specify. But back to my question my teacher requires a congruence postulate to proof the congruence. (ie, vertical angle property, reflexive property...)

Comment: what could <AEB= <CEB be?

Comment: @user118970:in that case, what's your teacher's definition of "perpendicular"?

Comment: the more i think about it it seems silly to say its not 90 degrees, so say the angles are 90 degrees what is the congruence postulate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this online version of [Euclid's Element](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/bookI.html).

Definition 10 is the meaning of perpendicular. Basically put, if the angles made between two lines are not equal to each other (or congruent in modern terms), then the two lines are not called "perpendicular".

Postulate #4 is the congruence postulate.

The rest is just Side-Angle-Side. Whether side-angle-side a postulate or a theorem depend on what your take on Euclid is.

Comment: ok thanks @Gina

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion based on symmetry.

Let $r$ be the reflection with respect to line $BD$. Since $BD$ is the perpendicular bisector of segment $AC$, $r(A) = C$ and $r(C) = A$. We also have $r(B) = B$, since $B$ is on the axis of the reflection.

The image of angle $\angle BAC$ under $r$ is $\angle BCA$. But reflections preserve angles. Therefore $\angle BAC = \angle BCA$.